# Is there something wrong with my A* Pathfinding Implementation?

Tags: java, libgdx, path-finding, a-star

So I'm trying to implement an A* PathFinding Algorithm in LibGDX so I can get an understanding of how it works. I based my implementation on this write up on it: <[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171022224528/http://www.policyalmanac.org:80/games/aStarTutorial.htm)>

At the moment, I have gotten the algorithm to calculate a path, and even return a path as non existing if the target is not accessible, however the route a found path takes is really unusual if there are walls partially blocking the target as you can see here:

[image: PathFinding Problem]

So what I'd like to find out is what is wrong with my implementation, to see why the Closed List is producing a path like this, or if I'm missing a step.

These are the variables in the PathFinder class:

```
public class PathFinder {
private Array<Array<GridNode>> grid = new Array<Array<GridNode>>();
private Array<GridNode> openPath = new Array<GridNode>();
private Array<GridNode> closedPath = new Array<GridNode>();
private int GridX, GridY;
private int StartX = -1, StartY = -1;
private int EndX = -1, EndY = -1;

public static int Found = 1;
public static int NonExistant = 2;
```

Here's the Path Finding code in the PathFinder class:

```
public int findPath()
{
    //Clear current path
    openPath.clear();
    closedPath.clear();
    
    //Reset all F, G and H values to 0
    for (int y = 0; y < grid.size; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < grid.get(y).size; x++)
        {
            grid.get(y).get(x).Reset();
        }
    }
    
    //If no Start or End nodes have been set, quit the findPath.
    if (StartX == -1 || StartY == -1 || EndX == -1 || EndY == -1)
    {
        return NonExistant;
    }
    else if (StartX == EndX && StartY == EndY) // If Start = End, return found.
    {
        return Found;
    }
    else
    {
        openPath.add(grid.get(StartY).get(StartX)); //Add Start node to open
        SetOpenList(StartX, StartY); //Set neighbours.
        
        closedPath.add(grid.get(StartY).get(StartX)); //Add Start node to closed.
        openPath.removeValue(grid.get(StartY).get(StartX),true); //Remove Start Node from open.
        
        while (closedPath.get(closedPath.size - 1) != grid.get(EndY).get(EndX))
        {
            //Set Neighbours for parent
            SetOpenList(closedPath.get(closedPath.size-1).X/GridX, closedPath.get(closedPath.size-1).Y/GridY);
            
            if (openPath.size != 0)
            {
                int bestF = 10000;
                int bestFIndex = -1;
                
                //Get node with lowest F in open.
                for (int i = 0; i < openPath.size; i++)
                {
                    if (openPath.get(i).F < bestF)
                    {
                        bestF = openPath.get(i).F;
                        bestFIndex = i;
                    }
                }
                
                if (bestFIndex != -1)
                {
                    closedPath.add(openPath.get(bestFIndex)); //Add node to closed list
                    openPath.removeIndex(bestFIndex); //remove from open list
                }
                else
                    return NonExistant;
            }
            else
            {
                return NonExistant;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return Found;
}

public void CompareParentwithOpen(GridNode Parent, GridNode Open)
{
    //If the G value of open is smaller than the G value in Parent, recalculate F, G and H.
    if (Open.G < Parent.G)
    {
        openPath.get(
                openPath.indexOf(Open, true)).CalculateNode(
                        Parent, 
                        grid.get(StartY).get(StartX), 
                        grid.get(EndY).get(EndX));
    }
}

public void SetOpenList(int X, int Y)
{
    //Check position of X and Y to avoid IndexOutofBounds.
    Boolean ignoreLeft = (X - 1 < 0);
    Boolean ignoreRight = (X + 1 >= grid.get(Y).size);
    Boolean ignoreUp = (Y - 1 < 0);
    Boolean ignoreDown = (Y + 1 >= grid.size);
    
    tempOpen = new Array<GridNode>();
    
    //For each check, if the checked grid is not an unpassable type and not in the closed list, continute checking.
    //If checked grid is already in Open List, go to Compare parent with open.
    if (!ignoreLeft && !ignoreUp)
    {
        if (grid.get(Y-1).get(X-1).type != GridNode.GridType.UNPASSABLE && 
                !closedPath.contains(grid.get(Y-1).get(X-1), true))
        {
            if (!(openPath.contains(grid.get(Y-1).get(X-1), true) || openPath.contains(grid.get(Y-1).get(X-1), false)))
            {
                grid.get(Y-1).get(X-1).CalculateNode(grid.get(Y).get(X), grid.get(StartY).get(StartX), grid.get(EndY).get(EndX));
                openPath.add(grid.get(Y-1).get(X-1));
            }
            else
            {
                CompareParentwithOpen(grid.get(Y).get(X), 
                        openPath.get(openPath.indexOf(grid.get(Y-1).get(X-1), true)));
            }
        }
    }
    
    if (!ignoreUp)
    {
        if (grid.get(Y-1).get(X).type != GridNode.GridType.UNPASSABLE && 
                !closedPath.contains(grid.get(Y-1).get(X), true))
        {
            if (!(openPath.contains(grid.get(Y-1).get(X), true) || openPath.contains(grid.get(Y-1).get(X), false)))
            {
                grid.get(Y-1).get(X).CalculateNode(grid.get(Y).get(X), grid.get(StartY).get(StartX), grid.get(EndY).get(EndX));
                openPath.add(grid.get(Y-1).get(X));
            }
            else
            {
                CompareParentwithOpen(grid.get(Y).get(X), 
                        openPath.get(openPath.indexOf(grid.get(Y-1).get(X), true)));
            }
        }
    }
    
    if (!ignoreRight && !ignoreUp)
    {
        if (grid.get(Y-1).get(X+1).type != GridNode.GridType.UNPASSABLE && 
                !closedPath.contains(grid.get(Y-1).get(X+1), true))
        {
            if (!(openPath.contains(grid.get(Y-1).get(X+1), true) || openPath.contains(grid.get(Y-1).get(X+1), false)))
            {
                grid.get(Y-1).get(X+1).CalculateNode(grid.get(Y).get(X), grid.get(StartY).get(StartX), grid.get(EndY).get(EndX));
                openPath.add(grid.get(Y-1).get(X+1));
            }
            else
            {
                CompareParentwithOpen(grid.get(Y).get(X), 
                        openPath.get(openPath.indexOf(grid.get(Y-1).get(X+1), true)));
            }
        }
    }
    
    if (!ignoreLeft)
    {
        if (grid.get(Y).get(X-1).type != GridNode.GridType.UNPASSABLE && 
                !closedPath.contains(grid.get(Y).get(X-1), true))
        {
            if (!(openPath.contains(grid.get(Y).get(X-1), true) || openPath.contains(grid.get(Y).get(X-1), false)))
            {
                grid.get(Y).get(X-1).CalculateNode(grid.get(Y).get(X), grid.get(StartY).get(StartX), grid.get(EndY).get(EndX));
                openPath.add(grid.get(Y).get(X-1));
            }
            else
            {
                CompareParentwithOpen(grid.get(Y).get(X), 
                        openPath.get(openPath.indexOf(grid.get(Y).get(X-1), true)));
            }
        }
    }
    
    if (!ignoreRight)
    {
        if (grid.get(Y).get(X+1).type != GridNode.GridType.UNPASSABLE && 
                !closedPath.contains(grid.get(Y).get(X+1), true))
        {
            if (!(openPath.contains(grid.get(Y).get(X+1), true) || openPath.contains(grid.get(Y).get(X+1), false)))
            {
                grid.get(Y).get(X+1).CalculateNode(grid.get(Y).get(X), grid.get(StartY).get(StartX), grid.get(EndY).get(EndX));
                openPath.add(grid.get(Y).get(X+1));
            }
            else
            {
                CompareParentwithOpen(grid.get(Y).get(X), 
                        openPath.get(openPath.indexOf(grid.get(Y).get(X+1), true)));
            }
        }
    }
    
    if (!ignoreLeft && !ignoreDown)
    {
        if (grid.get(Y+1).get(X-1).type != GridNode.GridType.UNPASSABLE && 
                !closedPath.contains(grid.get(Y+1).get(X-1), true))
        {
            if (!(openPath.contains(grid.get(Y+1).get(X-1), true) || openPath.contains(grid.get(Y+1).get(X-1), false)))
            {
                grid.get(Y+1).get(X-1).CalculateNode(grid.get(Y).get(X), grid.get(StartY).get(StartX), grid.get(EndY).get(EndX));
                openPath.add(grid.get(Y+1).get(X-1));
            }
            else
            {
                CompareParentwithOpen(grid.get(Y).get(X), 
                        openPath.get(openPath.indexOf(grid.get(Y+1).get(X-1), true)));
            }
        }
    }
    
    if (!ignoreDown)
    {
        if (grid.get(Y+1).get(X).type != GridNode.GridType.UNPASSABLE && 
                !closedPath.contains(grid.get(Y+1).get(X), true))
        {
            if (!(openPath.contains(grid.get(Y+1).get(X), true) || openPath.contains(grid.get(Y+1).get(X), false)))
            {
                grid.get(Y+1).get(X).CalculateNode(grid.get(Y).get(X), grid.get(StartY).get(StartX), grid.get(EndY).get(EndX));
                openPath.add(grid.get(Y+1).get(X));
            }
            else
            {
                CompareParentwithOpen(grid.get(Y).get(X), 
                        openPath.get(openPath.indexOf(grid.get(Y+1).get(X), true)));
            }
        }
    }
    
    if (!ignoreRight && !ignoreDown)
    {
        if (grid.get(Y+1).get(X+1).type != GridNode.GridType.UNPASSABLE && 
                !closedPath.contains(grid.get(Y+1).get(X+1), true))
        {
            if (!(openPath.contains(grid.get(Y+1).get(X+1), true) || openPath.contains(grid.get(Y+1).get(X+1), false)))
            {
                grid.get(Y+1).get(X+1).CalculateNode(grid.get(Y).get(X), grid.get(StartY).get(StartX), grid.get(EndY).get(EndX));
                openPath.add(grid.get(Y+1).get(X+1));
            }
            else
            {
                CompareParentwithOpen(grid.get(Y).get(X), 
                        openPath.get(openPath.indexOf(grid.get(Y+1).get(X+1), true)));
            }
        }
    }
    
    for (GridNode c : closedPath) //incase any nodes in closed are in open, remove closed nodes.
    {
        openPath.removeValue(c, true);
    }
}

public void SetGridNode(int screenX, int screenY, GridNode.GridType Type)
{
    int pointX = (int)(screenX/GridX);
    int pointY = (int)(screenY/GridY);
    
    if (pointY >= 0 && pointY < grid.size)
    {
        if (pointX >=0 && pointX < grid.get(pointY).size)
        {
            if (Type == GridNode.GridType.START || Type == GridNode.GridType.END)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < grid.size; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < grid.get(y).size; x++)
                    {
                        if (grid.get(y).get(x).type == Type)
                        {
                            if (Type == GridNode.GridType.START)
                            {
                                StartX = -1;
                                StartY = -1;
                            }
                            else if (Type == GridNode.GridType.END)
                            {
                                EndX = -1;
                                EndY = -1;
                            }
                            
                            grid.get(y).get(x).type = GridNode.GridType.NONE;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if (grid.get(pointY).get(pointX).type == Type)
                grid.get(pointY).get(pointX).type = GridNode.GridType.NONE;
            else
            {
                if (Type == GridNode.GridType.START)
                {
                    StartX = pointX;
                    StartY = pointY;
                }
                else if (Type == GridNode.GridType.END)
                {
                    EndX = pointX;
                    EndY = pointY;
                }
                
                grid.get(pointY).get(pointX).type = Type;
            }
        }
    }
}

public Array<GridNode> GetPath()
{
    return closedPath;
}
```

These are the variables in the GridNode class:

```
public class GridNode {
public int X = 0, Y = 0;
public int Width = 10, Height = 10;
public GridType type = GridType.NONE;
public int F = 0, G = 0, H = 0;

public static enum GridType
{
    NONE,
    UNPASSABLE,
    START,
    END
}
```

Here's the code to calculate the F, G and H values in the GridNode class:

```
public void CalculateNode(GridNode Parent, GridNode Start, GridNode End)
{
    if (Parent != null)
    {
        if (Math.abs(X - Parent.X) != 0 &&
                Math.abs(Y - Parent.Y) != 0)
        {
            G = Parent.G + 14;
        }
        else
        {
            G = Parent.G + 10;
        }
        
        H = (int)((Math.abs(X-End.X)/Width) + (Math.abs(Y - End.Y)/Height)) * 10;
        
        /*int xDistance = (Math.abs(X-End.X)/Width);
        int yDistance = (Math.abs(Y - End.Y)/Height);
        
        if (xDistance > yDistance)
            H = 14*yDistance + 10*(xDistance-yDistance);
        else
            H = 14*xDistance + 10*(yDistance-xDistance);*/
        
        F = G + H;
    }
}

public void Reset()
{
    F = G = H = 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems that you are doing integer division `H = (int)((Math.abs(X-End.X)/Width) + (Math.abs(Y - End.Y)/Height)) * 10;`. Why are you dividing anyway?

Comment: Because the X and Y components were written to be real world coordinates, not grid coordinates. Would that make a difference?

Comment: In GridNode class, you declared X and Y to be `int`, not `double` or `float`.

Comment: I've changed X and Y to floats, and that hasn't made a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem with the help from @KommaKameleon on Twitter. You can check out the [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/gamepopper/AStarLibGDX/) for the full working code.

Problem was that I was following all the steps for the writeup above. All except for the last step, which requires you to go through from the end point to the start point by each's nodes Parent.

Therefore, what I did was add a GridNode variable inside the GridNode class to store the Parent node used in calculating the F, G and H.

```
public class GridNode {
public float X = 0, Y = 0;
public int Width = 10, Height = 10;
public GridType type = GridType.NONE;
public float F = 0, G = 0, H = 0;
public GridNode Parent = null;
...

public void CalculateNode(GridNode Parent, GridNode Start, GridNode End)
{
    this.Parent = Parent;

    if (Parent != null)
    {
...
```

Then inside the findPath() method, after the while loop, I did another while loop to set up a new Array property called finalPath:

```
private Array<GridNode> finalPath = new Array<GridNode>();
```

This is the algortithm I used to go through each parent from the End Point to the Start Point. (where the End node is in the last element of the closedPath array)

```
GridNode g = closedPath.peek();
finalPath.add(g);

while (g != grid.get(StartY).get(StartX))
{
    g = g.Parent;
    finalPath.add(g);
}

finalPath.reverse();
```